# Can't figure out how to display javascript in Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have this link:

http://voap.weather.com/weather/oap/90210?template=GENXV&par=3000000007&unit=0&key=twciweatherwidget

if you copy and paste it in your browser, it acts the same as it does in my webview,
it is displaying   document.write("    and  ");
around the widget.

This is the code that that I am using in my Android app:

```
WebView wv = new WebView(this);

setContentView(wv);
String html = "http://xhtml.weather.com/xhtml/hbhf/90210";  

wv.loadUrl(html);
```

The code above displays the coded url just fine.

If I change the url to the one that I want to display (the one listed up on top), 
it displays the Document.Write as mentioned.

If I enable Javascript using:

```
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

and place the javascript wrapper around the url such as:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://voap.weather.com/weather/oap/90210?template=GENXV&par=3000000007&unit=0&key=twciweatherwidget"></script>
```

I notice right away that the double quotes are messing up the syntax.

I changed every double quote to " + (char) 39 + "

When I try running that code, I get a message that the url is invalid:

Here's a link to a screenshot:
http://davidmcafee.org/downloads/images/AndroidWeatherErr.png

It appears that the quotes are all in the correct place.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?
I am going nuts trying to figure out what it is.

I've searched and searched, but I am either missing something so simple, or I am searching for the wrong terms.

Comment: So.... What's the problem right now? Considering you said that if you open the first link you posted in your webview, it displays the widget with `document.write(" -widget- ");` around it, isn't that what you're looking for?  Cause it looks exactly the same on my phone in a `WebView` as it does on the browser on my desktop. If you're asking why the `document.write` part shows even though you have Javascript on, it's because there are no script tags around the code on the website itself. It's not because of your phone since it also shows in your normal browser, which is build to handle JS.

Comment: So is there anything I can do to remove the document.write? I would think the widget would display without it.

Comment: My guess is not unless you manage to change the actual response from the website. The `document.write` is not contained in any script tags on the website, showing it as plain text.