# Iframe display " document.write(" in webpage

Tags: javascript, iframe

[image]

I am using weather widget to display in website.

```
<iframe src="http://voap.weather.com/weather/oap/USGA0028?template=GENXH&par=3000000007&unit=0&key=twciweatherwidget" scrolling = "no" frameborder="0" width="270px" height="270px"></iframe>
```

when I display it in my web page, " document.write(" " appends above my Iframe. See scree shot attached.

I am unable to find what an issues is, any help guys.

Comment: Show the script you're using to embed this IFRAME.

Comment: <iframe src="http://voap.weather.com/weather/oap/USGA0028?template=GENXH&par=3000000007&unit=0&key=twciweatherwidget" scrolling = "no" frameborder="0" width="270px" height="270px"></iframe>

Comment: It looks like it's coming from the source, I can see the same thing in a `jsfiddle`

Comment: Yes, It works well when you use with script tag, but I need it in iframe

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461520/cant-figure-out-how-to-display-javascript-in-android-webview)

Comment: Is it not possible to remove document.write from HTML page. This is the only solution which I think of currently.

Comment: The script wasn't meant to be used as an `src` of an `iframe`. you better create your own html page with the script embedded in it, then load it inside your iframe.

Comment: If our solution helped you, please mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to remove the `document.write` tag due to **same-origin** restrictions. Instead, you should follow [haim770](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625737/haim770)'s suggestions to create a very simple page that includes the widget in a `script` tag (like it's supposed to be) and then put that page inside your `iframe`.

Answer (score 1):

The code problem is inside the iframe src

You will have to edit the page you are embedding ie.http://voap.weather.... and remove the document.write from there.

or if you cant edit the src page then you will have to modify the content inside it via javascript once the iframe is loaded.

P.S the weather widget is supposed to be used with  script tag

Comment: Yes we cant edit the src page. I was thinking to remove it via JS.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you got this widget from http://voap.weather.com/services/. But widget from there has been created using `<script>` tag. Did you simply changed script to iframe? Try to include source script tag with parameters in your site where widget should be placed. So you will need  no any code manipulations. For example

```
<div class="my-weather-div-class">
    <script src="http://voap.weather.com/weather/oap/USGA0028?template=GENXH&par=3000000007&unit=0&key=twciweatherwidget"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I knw it works well within script tag

Comment: @sham, but you need to use iframe?